# Azure Pipelines hosted agents deploying to VM with access restriction

Tags: azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine

I wanna deploy code on Linux VM in Azure with Azure Pipelines. The pipelines are using Microsoft hosted agents and the VM has access restrictions where I need to whitelist IP addresses. Since each deploy from Azure Pipelines is from different IP is there a way how to deploy to this VM without whitelisting each Microsoft agent IP address?

The only solution I found is to use self hosted agent.
Is there a way to accomplish deploy without whitelisting each public ip from every deploy on the VM?

Answer (score 0):

***As you’re using Microsoft Hosted agents, You might need to know the IP address range where a Microsoft Hosted agent is installed with particular configurations. If you want to limit access to the Microsoft hosted agents by IP address if you need to give them access through a firewall. The IP ranges change over time since Azure DevOps use the Azure global network. Azure Publishes weekly list of IP addresses in the json file refer here-  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519

Listing Azure datacenter IP ranges, separated by region. New proposed IP ranges are added to this file once each week. The following week sees the new IP ranges go into effect. To keep your list current, we advise that you return frequently (at least once per week).

You can check the available IP’s and whitelist those IP every week, As there’s no other workaround to get pass this varying IPs.

For above reference follow this document:-

[Microsoft-hosted agents for Azure Pipelines - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-ip-ranges)***

> But for now only self hosted agent is the alternative available if you
> do not want to update your IP’s every week.

Additionally you can go through this document to understand various IP’s and urls used by azure devops in general -  [Allowed address lists and network connections - Azure DevOps | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4)

As an alternative:-

> ***Using a self-hosted agent is the possible solution you can configure on Linux VM and set up firewall to permit traffic from a> certain IP address by using a self-hosted agent.***

[image]

Then try to connect with linux vm and create a folder and Download the agent:using below cmd:

```bash
~/$ mkdir myagent && cd myagent
~/myagent$ tar zxvf ~/Downloads/vsts-agent-linux-x64-3.218.0.tar.gz
```

To configure the agent :

```bash
~/myagent$ ./config.sh
```

To run the agent :

```bash
~/myagent$ ./run.sh
```

To create a Personal access token :

On user setting -> Personal access token

[image]

Allow permission on Agent pool read and manage like below:

[image]

To more in detail  ***refer***  this link

[Deploy an Azure Pipelines agent on Linux - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops)

Comment: How is this an answer to the question? The question is about **not** using a self-hosted agent. The asker is aware that this is an option, but is trying to avoid doing so.

Comment: @DanielMann, Thanks for pointing it out, I have added a few more details to my answer.